# Swift/Firestore: Completion doesn't get called

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, completionhandler

I'm trying to create a "Profile" collection in Firestore in order to store more data on my users than just their email/name.
I'm stuck with creating this document and uploading the profile picture they choose (as an URL).

Here is the function called when they click on the "Register" button:

```
func register() {
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: self.email, password: self.pass) { (res, err) in
                if err != nil {
                    self.error = err!.localizedDescription
                    self.alert.toggle()
                    return
                }
                // Success registering a new user
                guard let userUID = res?.user.uid else { return }

                uploadImageToFirestore(id: userUID, image: myImage) {
                    print("SUCCESS")
                    self.imageURL = downloadImageFromFirestore(id: userUID)
                    self.createUserDocument(id: userUID, imgURL: self.imageURL)
                }
        }
```

First step is uploading picture on Firebase Storage using the *uploadImageToFirestore* function and I tried using a completion handler to wait before calling the next 2 functions:

```
    func uploadImageToFirestore(id: String, image: UIImage, completion: () -> Void) {
    let storageRef = storage.reference().child("images/\(id)/image.jpg").putData(image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.35)!, metadata: nil) { (_, err) in
        if err != nil {
            print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
            return
        }
        print("Success uploading picture to Firestore")
    }
}
```

Second step is downloading the newly uploaded image on Firebase Storage to get the URL:

```
    func downloadImageFromFirestore(id: String) -> String {
    let storageRef = storage.reference().child("images/\(id)/image.jpg")
    storageRef.downloadURL { url, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("DEBUG: \((error?.localizedDescription)!)")
            return
        }
        print("Success downloading picture from Firestore")
        self.imageURL = "\(url!)"
    }
    return self.imageURL
}
```

Third step is creating the Profile collection in Firestore with the ImageURL:

```
    func createUserDocument(id: String, imgURL: String) {
    db.collection("profiles").document(id).setData([
        "name": name,
        "surname": surname,
        "email": email,
        "shelter": isMember == true ? shelters[selectedShelter] : shelters[0],
        "photoURL": imgURL,
        "reputation": 0,
        "uuid": id
    ])
    { err in
        if let error = err {
            print("Error ading document: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("New profile document created in Firestore")
        }
    }
}
```

**THE PROBLEM**

The problem I face is that in my "Register" function, the completion block of *uploadImageToFirestore* is never called, thus the function createUserDocument neither.

Is this the best way to achieve what I want (a.k.a. creating a profile document with the imageURL of the picture they just choose while registering)? Why is my completion block not called? (I don't see the "SUCCESS" printed in my console).

Thank you for your help!

Kind regards,
Jihaysse

Comment: You aren't calling the completion handler in `uploadImageToFirestore`.  It is your responsibility to invoke the passed closure.  I would also suggest that you define the  completion handler to accept a `Result` type so that you can pass success or failure with error to the closure

Comment: That sounds like the start of answer @Paulw11. :)

Comment: @Paulw11 answer is excellent. I would like to add three things; the code in the question is using a number of callbacks and misses some error handling which could probably be greatly simplified as the download url is available directly after the upload. See the documentation [Upload from memory](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_data_in_memory).

Comment: Also I noticed you're populating  a class var with the url `self.imageURL = "\(url!)"` and then also *returning* that from the function which is not needed - no reason to return something that's available classwide. More importantly, the `return self.imageURL` will be called before the `.downloadURL` function completes as its asynchronous and the code after the closure will execute before the code in the closure (sometimes). So then this `self.imageURL = downloadImageFromFirestore(id: userUID)` gets kinda weird as it may sometimes be an empty string.

Comment: Those are  good points. I didn't look at the rest of code the code, I just saw the issue with the completion handler not being called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the completion handler closure that you are passing to `uploadImageToFirestore`.

You should probably also pass the `error`, if any, so that you can handle it.

```
func uploadImageToFirestore(id: String, image: UIImage, completion: (Error?) -> Void) {
    let storageRef = storage.reference().child("images/\(id)/image.jpg").putData(image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.35)!, metadata: nil) { (_, err) in
        completion(err)
    }
}
```